# -[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile] returning nil on iPad; returning dictionary in the simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a method:

```
#define ROOT_ASSETS_PATH @"/assets/"
```

...

```
-(NSMutableDictionary*) getContentsOfPlist{
    NSString *pageContentPlistPath = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: ROOT_ASSETS_PATH] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"content.plist"];

    NSMutableDictionary *mDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:pageContentPlistPath];
    return mDicitonary;
}
```

On the simulator. this returns a dictionary.  On the iPad, it returns nil.  Made sure the extension case matches that in the call as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"contents" ofType:@"plist]`. And `contents.plist` might be reserved, you should probably name it something else.

Comment: Just using the name for this example.  It has a more unique name in my app.

Comment: on the device names are case sensitive, on the simulator not. double check that

Comment: Just checked.  Case WAS the issue ... :/  Thx!

Comment: FYI - don't put the slashes in your `ROOT_ASSETS_PATH`. Just assign `@"assets"`. Calls to `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` will add the proper path separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was case after all.  Case of the filename didn't match the case I put in the parameter.  OSX doesn't care, but the iPad does.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the slashes in your #define.  stringByAppendingPathComponent will add the slashes for you.  Not sure why this would work in the Simulator.

Comment: I think it handles slashes, though.  I'm not getting double slashes anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Also it is good idea to use:

```
[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:options:format:error:]
```

Instead of direct NSDictionary initialization. If something will fail, it should return a nice error for you.

Comment: Problem was case after all, but I'll look into this.  I didn't know this was a thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (id)dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
```

> **Parameters**
>
> *path*
>
> A full or relative pathname. The file identified by path must contain
>   a string representation of a property list whose root object is a
>   dictionary.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> A new dictionary that contains the dictionary at path, or nil if there
>   is a file error or if the contents of the file are an invalid
>   representation of a dictionary.

So, you have to set a full path to your file (or an appropriate relative path)

Note also that the app bundle is read-write on Simulator but read-only on device.